# SharePoint Online Copy / Move Destination Missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, move, copy

Trying to move / copy  files from one document library to another.  One location is a top site and the second destination is a sub-site.

If I try to move / copy **from** the subsite library to the top site library, I can see the top site in the "Choose Destination" site list and copy / move to it.

But the opposite does not work.  The sub-site and it's document library **is not visible** when trying to move files from the top site library to the subsite library.  I am "following" both the parent site and the subsite (both are starred).

Any idea what to do to have the sub-site show up in the "Choose Destination"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible your sub-site is not configured to appear in search results which will prevent it from appearing in your Move/Copy-To destination list in OneDrive (or another SharePoint site). Try the following steps:

1. Go to Site Settings
2. In the Search category, select "Search and offline availability"
3. Be sure the option for "Allow this site to appear in search results?" is set to "Yes"

Save your changes, and then go back into "Search and offline availability" to reindex the site. Give it an hour or so and then try moving a file from another library.

I battled this problem for a good month and the above steps worked like a charm.